# Decipherment of preprocessor statement

Tags: c-preprocessor, string-concatenation, stringification

Could somebody please help me to decipher the following 
preprocessor statement.

```
#define ALLOC(x,y)     x _##y; x* y = &_##y;
```

I am aware that here some memory allocation for some variable y of type x is done.
But I am not sure what is the purpose of the ## in the statement above is. Would be great if somebody could help me out.

Comment: Are you aware that you can just run the pre-processor to see how it processes it? I know it's nice to understand, but once you have the understanding and what to test it out with something concrete, then the preprocessor can be run stand alone.

Answer (score 4):

That's known as [token pasting operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor#Token_concatenation).

Answer (score 3):

The token pasting operator (##) is used when you need to make one token out of two (or more) separate tokens.

without it, i.e.

```
#define ALLOC(x,y) x _y; x* y = &_y;

ALLOC(a,b)
```

would expand into:

```
a _y; a* b = &_y;
```

because the preprocessor knows to replace y with b but _y is another token altogether.

with the ## operator (i.e. your example)

```
ALLOC(a,b)
```

would expand into:

```
a _b; a* b = &_b;
```

## joins the token `_` and the token `b` to form the token `_b`

Answer (score 1):

A usage such as

```
ALLOC(int, integer)
```

would create the following code at the place where the macro is called:

```
int  _integer;
int* integer = &_integer;
```

Comment: Or, in English, "allocate" an object of type `x` on the stack and make `y` point to it.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly ## means concatenating the "strings itself".

example for your case ALLOC(int,var2) == > int_var2; int* var2 = &_var2